# Can I modify my html/css files easily after deploying them with FireBase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

This is my first time making a website and I am now trying to deploy it.

I have created my website so far using html/css/bootstrap, and plan on adding javascript afterwards.

I am in the middle of deploying it using FireBase hosting, I'd simply like to know how difficult is it to modify my files after I deploy them? I still might need to make a few changes and maybe add a file or two.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify any previously deployed content, just deploy again.  The conetnt you deploy will replace the prior deployment.

Comment: If you want to update individual files, that *is* possible through some custom code, but it's definitely a lot more involved. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34601488/can-i-add-additional-file-to-my-firebase-hosted-static-website-or-must-i-deploy/34601583#34601583